# How can I create a std::vector with 64 bit indexes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, 64-bit, allocator

I want to create a **big** `std::vector` so `operator[]` should receive `long long` rather than `unsigned int`, I tried writing my own allocator:

```
template <typename T>
struct allocator64 : std::allocator<T> {
    typedef long long difference_type;
    typedef unsigned long long size_type;
};
```

But when I try the following:

```
long long n = 5;
std::vector<int, allocator64<int> > vec(n);
vec[n-1] = 2;
```

I get the following warning for the second and third line:

> warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from '__int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

What am I missing? I thought the type for `operator[]` and for the size constructor should come from `allocator::size_type`.

I'm using VS9 (2008).

Comment: I believe you need a compiler where size_t is 64 bits

Comment: Why do you need over 4 billion indexes? I think you may need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the [**STXXL**](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net) library can help:

> STXXL provides an STL replacement
>   using an abstraction layer to  storage
>   devices to allow for the optimal
>   layout of data structures. This 
>   allows for multi-terabyte datasets to
>   be held and manipulated in standard 
>   C++ data structures, whilst
>   abstracting the complexity of managing
>   this  behaviour efficiently. STXXL
>   utilises multi-disk I/O to speed up 
>   I/O bound calculations. STXXL has been
>   developed at the University  of
>   Karlsruhe.

Comment: It does -- haven't used it myself but it is only an 'apt-get install' away on my Debian box.  And for infrastructure like this I personally don't want to spend time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: How does that implement pointers-to-elements? As of the corrigenda, it is a requirement of std::vector that `&vec[0]` be a T*, and that `&vec[n] == &vec[0] + n` for all `n < vec.size()`. I don't see how you can do that if your vector is an adapter for disk storage. It's a limitation of the Container concept in C++ that reference is defined as "lvalue T", not just as something assignable from and convertible to T. So it can't be a proxy object AFAIK.

Comment: The advantage of that limitation, btw, is that you can write `T &ref = vec[0];`, instead of having to do `std::vector<T>::reference &ref = vec[0];`, like with iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to store more than `numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` entries in the vector? O.o

If not then just cast n-1 to int explicitly: int(n-1)

Anyway, the argument is of type `vector::size_type` (and not allocator::size_type, as far as I know) which is usually a typedef to size_t (but needs not be); it may be 4 bytes or 8 or other amounts; it is implementation defined.

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ctzdcb6%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: `vector::size_type` is `typedef`ed to `allocator::size_type` at least in visual studio. Looking at the standard I now see 23.1 that `size_type` is implementation defined.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of vector provided with your compiler already uses the largest integer type that it usefully can[*], usually `size_t`. Suppose you're on a machine with a 32bit address space, and you say you want a vector with 2^33 elements. There's no way that can be allocated, and changing the parameter type of `operator[]` would not give your computer the ability to allocate bigger blocks of memory.

So, make sure that you're compiling your code for 64bit Windows, and all should be well.

[*] That's not guaranteed by the standard. But compiler-writers don't actually enjoy putting in limits for no reason, even if it sometimes looks that way.